# perl array prints as GLOB(#x#########)

Tags: perl, split

I have a file which contains a list of email addresses which are separated by a semi-colon which is configured much like this (but much larger) :

```
$ cat email_casper.txt
casper1@foo.com; casper2@foo.com; casper3@foo.com; casper.casper4@foo.com;

#these throw outlook error :
#casper101@foo.com ; casper100@foo.com
#cat /tmp/emailist.txt | tr '\n' '; '
#cat /tmp/emallist.txt | perl -nle 'print /\<(.*)\>/' | sort
```

I want to break it up on the semicolon - so I suck the whole file into an array supposedly the contents are split on semicolon.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $filename = shift @ARGV ;
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";

my @values = split(';', $fh);

foreach my $val (@values) {
    print "$val\n";
}

exit 0 ;
```

But the file awards me with a golb. I just don't know what is going one.

```
$ ./spliton_semi.pl email_casper.txt
GLOB(0x80070b90)
```

If I use Data::Dumper I get

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper ;
my $filename = shift @ARGV ;
open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die "Could not open file $filename $!";
my @values = split(';', $fh);
print Dumper \@values ;
```

This is what the Dumper returns :

```
$ ./spliton_semi.pl email_casper.txt
$VAR1 = [
          'GLOB(0x80070b90)'
        ];
```

Answer (score 3):

You do not "suck the whole file into an array". You don't even attempt to read from the file handle. Instead, you pass the file handle to `split`. Expecting a string, it stringifies the file handle into `GLOB(0x80070b90)`.

You could read the file into an array of lines as follows:

```
my @lines = <$fh>;
for my $line ($lines) {
   ...
}
```

But it's far simpler to read one line at a time.

```
while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {
   ...
}
```

In fact, there is no reason not to use `ARGV` here, simplifying your program to the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw( say );

while (<>) {
   chomp;
   say for split /\s*;\s*/, $_;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This line

```
my @values = split(';', $fh);
```

is not reading from the filehandle like you think it is.  You're actually calling `split` on the filehandle object itself.

You want this:

```
my $line = <$fh>;
my @values = split(';', $line);
```

Comment: only with error checking; as is, that will give a warning if there was no line to read

Answer (score 0):

Starting point:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open(my $fh, '<', 'dummy.txt')
    or die "$!";

my @values;
while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    # original
    # push(@values, split(';', $_));
    # handle white space
    push(@values, split(/\s*;\s*/, $_));
}

close($fh);

foreach my $val (@values) {
    print "$val\n";
}

exit 0;
```

Output for your example:

```
$ perl dummy.pl
casper1@foo.com
casper2@foo.com
casper3@foo.com
casper.casper4@foo.com
```